# Can I use bundle to upgrade rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I have been able to successfully upgraded from 3.0.1 to 3.0.6 by editing the Gemfile and bundle update...

I like the fact that if something goes wrong I can revert back to the version 3.0.1

Is is also possible to upgrade to rails 3.1.1 just using bundle and go back to 3.0.6 if something does not work in the rails version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler just point your app to the right libraries (and, of course download all dependencies!).

Your app needs to fit the proper version of the libraries. So is it for Rails.

To conclude, you can't upgrade from rails 3.0.x to 3.1.x via bundler but there is a Railscast for this :)